# Many-to-Many searching with Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I would like to use Sphinx for many to many matching.  I took the questions and tags case here in StackOverflow for illustration.

A question can be associated with many tags and vice versa for a tag.

So in the mysql, I have 3 tables: question, tag, question_tag.

I would like to search for questions which contains as many tags in the set "java", "sphinx", "mysql", "hibernate" as possible.  So the result might come up with questions with 3 matches, 2 matches or 1 match.

Currently, I create a field which concat all these tags with space and have sphinx search that field.  But it sounds silly and create a lot of overhead when adding and removing tags.  There gonna be some smarter way, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at MVA - Multi Value Attributes, in the documentation [MVA](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/mva.html) and
[sql_attr_multi](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-sql-attr-multi.html).

I have used this in the past to search "interests" against a "person". So I may like rock music and watching rugby. Sphinx can index this in an array and you can search them using OR or AND matching.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest should be to just join the tables and group by the question ID. Sphinx does the rest for you:

```
source src_questions{
  select question_id, question_subject, question_body, tag_value from question \
  JOIN question_tag on question.question_id = question_tag.question_id \
  JOIN tag on question_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
  GROUP BY question_id 
}
```

that assumes, that you've got the following columns in your tables

**question table:**

```
question_id INT
question_subject VARCHAR or TEXT
question_body VARCHAR or TEXT
```

**tag table:**

```
tag_id INT
tag_value VARCHAR or TEXT
```

**question_tag_table:**

```
question_id INT
tag_id INT
```

Comment: Since it's a many2many case, you will create many records for the same questions.  Another more serious problem is that if the question meets more than 1 keyword of your search phase, the rating is still low.